# Speeding up NDSolve for oscillatory differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of second order differential equation, over time, which has periods of fast changing profile, and I need to evaluate the equation around that transition.
I have to run it over a scan of points, thus time per point needs to be below O(1) second. The trouble is that for some of the values, the ODE doesn't wanna solve and spits "Indeterminate" or "Complex Infinity". I tried using MaxStepSize, but that only leads to bogus values as results.
I also tried to increase the time interval over which my equation is being evaluated, and although it is giving sensible answers, it takes O(1000) seconds for a single point, making it untenable.

I am attaching the code for one specific point, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there are any further clarifications needed.

```
(*VALUES FOR VARIABLES USED*)

fa = 1.13*10^13;
Rf = 0.0104;
\[Theta] = 1;  
\[Phi] = 1;
Mpl = 12*10^18; 
\[CapitalLambda]qcd = 2/10;
f\[CurlyPhi] = Rf* fa;
ma$t[t_] = 
 If[t < Mpl/(2 \[CapitalLambda]qcd^2), ma (\[CapitalLambda]qcd/Sqrt[Mpl/(2 t)])^4,  ma]; 

t1 = (Mpl^2/(8 ma \[CapitalLambda]qcd^4))^(1/3);
ma =  57*10^-16 (10^12/fa); 

Rm = Rf^4 (3/10 87/10 24/10 1/1000 (fa/10^12)^(3/2))/(11/100);
m\[CurlyPhi] = Rm ma;

(* Mass matrix eigenvalues *)

mH$t[t_] = Sqrt[1/2 ma$t[t]^2 (1 + Rm^2 ma^2/ma$t[t]^2 (1 + Rf^2 + 
        Sqrt[(1 - Rf^2 - 1/Rm^2 ma$t[t]^2/ma^2)^2 + 4 Rf^2]))];

mL$t[t_] = Sqrt[1/2 ma$t[t]^2 (1 + Rm^2 ma^2/ma$t[t]^2 (1 + Rf^2 - 
        Sqrt[(1 - Rf^2 - 1/Rm^2 ma$t[t]^2/ma^2)^2 + 4 Rf^2]))];

(*Initial and final solving time, increasing the final times makes the equation take forever*)
ti = t1/1000; 
tf = t1 250;

(*DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION*)

eqns = {a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t] + ma$t[t]^2 a[t] + m\[CurlyPhi]^2 Rf^2 a[t] + 
       m[CurlyPhi]^2 Rf\[CurlyPhi][t] == 0, \[CurlyPhi]''[t] + 3/(2 t) \[CurlyPhi]'[t] + 
       m\[CurlyPhi]^2 \[CurlyPhi][t] + m\[CurlyPhi]^2 Rf a[t] == 0, a'[ti] == 0,           
       \[CurlyPhi]'[ti] == 0, a[ti] == \[Theta] fa, \[CurlyPhi][ti] ==                   
       \[Phi]f[CurlyPhi]};

{{sol1, sol2}} = NDSolve[eqns, {a[t], \[CurlyPhi][t]}, {t, ti, tf}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
                 PrecisionGoal -> 6];
```

UPDATE : Thanks a lot to Alex, and  following his solution involving dimensionless quantities and NDSolve method tricks, it speeded up the evaluation, and also realizing that I had to solve until t0 at max, I used "ADAMS" method. But for some points, I realized that using "BDF" actually resolved the issue better, so would like to understand why's that.

The query can be thought in a generic way : which Methods and tactics are best used for solving 2nd order ODEs, which have solutions which start at some initial value, slowly roll towards it's minima and then oscillate around it.

As an example, am putting in the updated code:

````
\[Theta] = 1; 
\[Phi] = 1;

fa = 2.1544346900318835855901063672841`10.*^12;

ma = 57 10^-16 (10^12/fa);  (* GeV axion mass *)
t1 = (Mpl^2/(
  8 ma \[CapitalLambda]qcd^4))^(
 1/3); (* GeV^-1 time when ma(T) = H(T) *)

t0 = Mpl/(2 \[CapitalLambda]qcd^2)/t1;

Rf = 0.6256495158757365`

fphi = f\[CurlyPhi] = Rf* fa;

Rm =0.0116328;

mphi = m\[CurlyPhi] = Rm ma;


m0[t_] := ma (\[CapitalLambda]qcd/Sqrt[Mpl/(2 t1 t)])^4;
madt[t_] := ma*If[t < t0, m0[t]/ma, 1];


mHDt[t_] := 
  Sqrt[1/2 madt[t]^2 (1 + 
      Rm^2 ma^2/
        madt[t]^2 (1 + Rf^2 + 
         Sqrt[(1 - Rf^2 - 1/Rm^2 madt[t]^2/ma^2)^2 + 4 Rf^2]))];
mLDt[t_] := 
  Sqrt[1/2 madt[t]^2 (1 + 
      Rm^2 ma^2/
        madt[t]^2 (1 + Rf^2 - 
         Sqrt[(1 - Rf^2 - 1/Rm^2 madt[t]^2/ma^2)^2 + 4 Rf^2]))];

    
ti = 1/1000;
tlc = t0 (1 - Rf^2)^(1/4) Sqrt[
  Rm];
tf =  4 tlc; a0 = \[Theta]*fa; phi0 = \[Phi]*fphi;

time = {t, ti, tf};
qvars = {a[t], \[CurlyPhi][t]};

(*DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION*)

eqns = {(a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t]) + t1^2 madt[t]^2 a[t] + 
      t1^2 mphi^2 Rf^2 a[t] + t1^2 mphi^2 Rf phi0/a0 \[CurlyPhi][t] ==
      0, (\[CurlyPhi]''[t] + 3/(2 t) \[CurlyPhi]'[t]) + 
      t1^2 mphi^2 \[CurlyPhi][t] + t1^2 mphi^2 Rf a0/phi0 a[t] == 0, 
    a'[ti] == 0, \[CurlyPhi]'[ti] == 0, 
    a[ti] == 1, \[CurlyPhi][ti] == 1} // Simplify;

solA = NDSolve[eqns, {a, \[CurlyPhi]}, time, StartingStepSize -> 1/20,
     Method -> "BDF", InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
```
````

Comment: Actually your code doesn't run. Several parameters are ti be defined!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks a lot for your comment. I tried to copy the above code in my machine and it ran fine, I think it might be the case of the names of variables( curly phi etc) which are not showing up correctly when we copy it to the mathematica notebook.

Answer (score 5):

To simplify code we use substitutions `f\[CurlyPhi]->fphi, m\[CurlyPhi]->mphi, ma$t->madt, mH$t->mHDt, mL$t->mLDt, t->t/t1, a->a/a0, \[CurlyPhi]->\[CurlyPhi]/phi0` where `a0 = \[Theta] fa; phi0 = \[Phi] fphi`. In this variables code can be written as follows

```
(*VALUES FOR VARIABLES USED*)
fa = 1.13*10^13;
Rf = 0.0104;
\[Theta] = 1;
\[Phi] = 1;
Mpl = 12*10^18;
\[CapitalLambda]qcd = 2/10;
fphi = Rf*fa;


t1 = (Mpl^2/(8 ma \[CapitalLambda]qcd^4))^(1/3);
ma = 57*10^-16 (10^12/fa);

Rm = Rf^4 (3/10 87/10 24/10 1/1000 (fa/10^12)^(3/2))/(11/100);
mphi = Rm ma; t0 = Mpl/(2 \[CapitalLambda]qcd^2)/t1; 
m0[t_] := ma (\[CapitalLambda]qcd/Sqrt[Mpl/(2 t1 t)])^4;

(*Mass matrix eigenvalues*)
madt[t_] := ma If[t < t0, m0[t]/ma, 1];
mHDt[t_] = 
  Sqrt[1/2 madt[t]^2 (1 + 
      Rm^2 ma^2/
        madt[t]^2 (1 + Rf^2 + 
         Sqrt[(1 - Rf^2 - 1/Rm^2 madt[t]^2/ma^2)^2 + 4 Rf^2]))];

mLDt[t_] = 
  Sqrt[1/2 madt[t]^2 (1 + 
      Rm^2 ma^2/
        madt[t]^2 (1 + Rf^2 - 
         Sqrt[(1 - Rf^2 - 1/Rm^2 madt[t]^2/ma^2)^2 + 4 Rf^2]))];

(*Initial and final solving time,increasing the final times makes the \
equation take forever*)
ti = 1/1000;
tf = 250; a0 = \[Theta] fa; phi0 = \[Phi] fphi;
(*DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION*)
eqns = {(a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t]) + t1^2 madt[t]^2 a[t] + 
     t1^2 mphi^2 Rf^2 a[t] + t1^2 mphi^2 Rf phi0/a0 \[CurlyPhi][t] == 
    0, (\[CurlyPhi]''[t] + 3/(2 t) \[CurlyPhi]'[t]) + 
     t1^2 mphi^2 \[CurlyPhi][t] + t1^2 mphi^2 Rf a0/phi0 a[t] == 0, 
   a'[ti] == 0, \[CurlyPhi]'[ti] == 0, 
   a[ti] == 1, \[CurlyPhi][ti] == 1} // Simplify
```

Now it tak3s about 75s on my laptop

```
sol = NDSolve[eqns, {a, \[CurlyPhi]}, {t, ti, tf}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Visualization

```
Plot[a[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, ti, tf}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "a"}]

Plot[\[CurlyPhi][t] /. sol[[1]], {t, ti, tf}, PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "\[CurlyPhi]"}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Update 1. Let check equation for `a`, we have

```
a[t]*(1.396316111230277*^-13 + 2.0160295703419477*^6*If[t < 53.28920267804457, m0[t]/ma, 1]^2) + 1.396316111230277*^-13*\[CurlyPhi][t] + (3*Derivative[1][a][t])/(2*t) + Derivative[2][a][t] ==0
```

In this range of parameters we can drop small member  `1.396316111230277*^-13*\[CurlyPhi][t]`, and  solve equation for `a` separately for `t<t0` and `t>t0` in the form

```
sol2 = 
 DSolve[{a[t] k t^4 + (3 Derivative[1][a][t])/(
      2 t) + (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 0, 
    Derivative[1][a][1/1000] == 0, a[1/1000] == 1}, a, t][[1]]

Out[]= {a -> 
  Function[{t}, -((-Sqrt[k] BesselJ[-(11/12), Sqrt[k]/
          3000000000] BesselJ[-(1/12), (Sqrt[k] t^3)/3] + 
        500000000 BesselJ[-(1/12), (Sqrt[k] t^3)/3] BesselJ[1/12, 
          Sqrt[k]/3000000000] + 
        Sqrt[k] BesselJ[-(13/12), Sqrt[k]/3000000000] BesselJ[1/12, (
          Sqrt[k] t^3)/3] - 
        500000000 BesselJ[-(1/12), Sqrt[k]/3000000000] BesselJ[1/12, (
          Sqrt[k] t^3)/3] - 
        Sqrt[k] BesselJ[1/12, (Sqrt[k] t^3)/3] BesselJ[11/12, Sqrt[k]/
          3000000000] + 
        Sqrt[k] BesselJ[-(1/12), (Sqrt[k] t^3)/3] BesselJ[13/12, Sqrt[
          k]/3000000000])/(10^(3/4) Sqrt[k] t^(
        1/4) (BesselJ[-(11/12), Sqrt[k]/3000000000] BesselJ[-(1/12), 
            Sqrt[k]/3000000000] - 
          BesselJ[-(13/12), Sqrt[k]/3000000000] BesselJ[1/12, Sqrt[k]/
            3000000000] + 
          BesselJ[1/12, Sqrt[k]/3000000000] BesselJ[11/12, Sqrt[k]/
            3000000000] - 
          BesselJ[-(1/12), Sqrt[k]/3000000000] BesselJ[13/12, Sqrt[k]/
            3000000000])))]} 


sol3 = 
 DSolve[a[t] k1 + (3 Derivative[1][a][t])/(
     2 t) + (a^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 0, a, t][[1]]

Out[]= {a -> 
  Function[{t}, (BesselJ[1/4, Sqrt[k1] t] C[1])/t^(1/4) + (
    BesselY[1/4, Sqrt[k1] t] C[2])/t^(1/4)]}
```

We can compare exact solution `sol2` with numerical solution as follows

```
Show[Plot[a[t] /. sol2 /. k -> 1/4, {t, ti, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, Frame -> True],Plot[a[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, ti, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Update 2. To reduce computation time we can use different strategy at `t<t0`, and `t>t0` as follows

```
time = {t, ti, t0};
qvars = {a[t], \[CurlyPhi][t]}; 
 solL = NDSolve[eqn, {a, \[CurlyPhi]}, time, StartingStepSize -> 1/20,
    Method -> "Adams", InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes about 1s only. Using `solL` we can compute initial data for the next step

```
ini = Flatten[{qvars, D[qvars, t]} /. solL /. t -> t0]

eqn1 = {(a''[t] + 3/(2 t) a'[t]) + t1^2 ma^2 a[t] + 
     t1^2 mphi^2 Rf^2 a[t] + t1^2 mphi^2 Rf phi0/a0 \[CurlyPhi][t] == 
    0, (\[CurlyPhi]''[t] + 3/(2 t) \[CurlyPhi]'[t]) + 
     t1^2 mphi^2 \[CurlyPhi][t] + t1^2 mphi^2 Rf a0/phi0 a[t] == 0, 
   a'[t0] == ini[[3]], \[CurlyPhi]'[t0] == ini[[4]], 
   a[t0] == ini[[1]], \[CurlyPhi][t0] == ini[[2]]};

solA = NDSolve[eqn1, {a, \[CurlyPhi]}, {t, t0, tf}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "BDF", 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It takes about 18 s. We can compare exact solution `sol2` with numerical solution `solL` as follows

```
Show[Plot[a[t] /. sol2 /. k -> 1/4, {t, ti, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, Frame -> True],Plot[a[t] /. solL[[1]], {t, ti, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Dashed}]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks a lot for your answer. I think it is a good strategy to use dimensionless quantities as implied in your solution, but I think we are still getting O(100) seconds as the time per point. I tried using MaxStepSize, which lead to bogus answer. Using PrecisionGoal->5, it cut down the time by half, still it is a lot as I need to scan over around 10^3 or 10^4 points. Do you have any suggestions which can speed things up considerably?

Comment: Maybe we can use exact solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks again for the updates. I think the exact solution obtained by dropping the other term, which resulted in the coupled ODE defeats the purpose of my problem since I would be scanning over possible points where it is very important.

Comment: On another note, the Update 2 part of partitioning the time interval looks promising to me. I wanted to ask if you had defined the t_0 somewhere which you were using in the example, or did you pick some value looking at the function's profile which separates the regions judiciously. Thanks again, these answers are definitely helpful in general for dealing with NDSolve!

Comment: @MuditRai Parameter `t0 = Mpl/(2 \[CapitalLambda]qcd^2)/t1` has been defined in the code before `m0[t_]:=`. Actually this is normalized parameter from your function `ma$t[t_] =  If[t < Mpl/(2 \[CapitalLambda]qcd^2)`

Comment: Thanks! I will think about it more in the context of my problem if the partitioning can be optimized in a better way.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I realised that I don;t have to evaluate the code further than t0, so in principle first part of your SolL does the job. But I run into issues, for some parameter points, and it gives "NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == 0.001`; unable to continue." Do you know what might be the resolution be?

Comment: I should have asked it earlier, but what's the difference b/w Adams vs BDF - and in general which method is best for oscillatory behaving equation solutions? Maybe if there's a reference I would be glad to read it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MuditRai Could you show your code as update to your post?

Comment: Hi @Alex, I just realized that using BDF did a better job in solving the ODE, and it doesn't give a problem. I can put them as a query in the update if that works?

Comment: @MuditRai Your question about Adams and BDF methods is good one, but not suitable for this forum.  See, for instance  https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=Adams+method and https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=BDF+method

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex for the useful references.